# if - else does not work in laravel framework blade templating

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel, laravel-blade

My question is, I have page as Laravel blade template.
If user  logged in, my page should be extended from a master layout.
If user did not login, my page should be extended from another master layout.

But my if- else statement does not working

```
 <?php 
 if (Auth::check()){?>
 @extends('layouts.outside');
 <?php } else{ ?>
     @extends('layouts.admin');
 <?php }?>
```

I also tried blade if-else version as follows:

```
@if (Auth::check())
 @extends('layouts.outside')
@else
 @extends('layouts.admin')
@endif
```

It did not work too. Every time wheter the statement true or false the block in if and else statement works one after. As there is no if else.
I mean every time it calls layouts.outside one time one and just bottom of it the same page is loaded  again with layouts.outside, whether not matter if the user logged in or not.

Thanks

Comment: You just forgot a `{` at the end of your `else` statement! Also at the start of the `else` statement your php opening tags you have to delete

Comment: `Auth::check()` shouldn't really be inside a view. Usually, something like this goes in `routes.php`, `filters.php` or a controller you've created. Just some food for thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if (Auth::check()){
Blade::extends('layouts.outside');
<?php } else 
extends('layouts.admin');
}?>
```

You are missing a { at the else
also why that php tag remove it

```
     <?php
        if (Auth::check()){
        Blade::extends('layouts.outside');
        } else{ 
        extends('layouts.admin');
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: He also has a opening tag to much!

Comment: Yes i saw it just was to fast by clicking on post.

Comment: I am really really sorry :( now I am so frustrated then I could not ask it correctly. But i corrected the question right now. Thanks for quick reply. I will be careful about tags next time @Rizier123 :)

Comment: @Soyaslan Please don't just do `Stealth edits`, Mark it clearly as an edit if you change your question! Like know the answer here is wrong to your question now, but was right to the original one!

Comment: Its alot esier to avoid these kinds of issued if you use the colon syntax like: `<?php if(): ?> <!-- stuff --> <?php else: ?> <!-- stuff --> <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Or just use the blade template syntax altogether `@if(...)` `@else(...)` `@endif`

Answer (score 9):

```
@extends(Auth::user() ? 'layouts.outside' : 'layouts.admin');
```